# Error while writing code for face recognition using haarcascade classifier

Tags: python, opencv

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

#Init camera

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

#Face Detection using haarcascade File

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\cv2\data\haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml')

skip = 0

face_data = []
#dataset_path = ('./Face Recognition Data')

while True:
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    if ret == False:
        continue

    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(frame,1.3,5)

    #The next line of code is written to only store the largest face in the window frame
    faces = sorted(faces,key = lambda  f: f[2]*f[3])

    #start sorting from the last face since the last face is the largest in terms of area(w*h)
    for face in faces[-1:] :
        x,y,w,h = face
        cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,255),2)

        #extract the required face or the region of the interest
        #Refers to adding an extra 10 pixels on all the sides of the required extracted face
        offset = 10
        #By default face slicing is done in (y,x) manner
        face_section = frame[y-offset:y+h+offset,x-offset:x+w+offset]
        face_section = cv2.resize(face_section,(100,100))

        if skip%10==0 : #Store every 10th frame
            face_data.append(face_section)
            print(len(face_data)) #number of faces captured so far

    cv2.imshow("Video Frame",frame)
    cv2.imshow("Face section frame",face_section)
    key_pressed = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if key_pressed == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

After running the program, it says that face_section variable is not defined. 
Please help

Comment: The `face_section` variable is defined within the `for` loop. If you get an error saying that the variable is not defined, then the loop is probably not working/doing what you expect

Comment: But then how to change the for loop in a manner to get the desired result?

Comment: I've never used the cv2 library so i cannot tell like this what is wrong. But this is what programing is, wrinting some code and then investigating if it does what is expected. The first step here could be to add a `print` call to the loop or to print the length of `faces`, to see if the `faces` list is empty and the loop doesn't get called in the first place

Answer (score 0):

You have more than one `face_section`. If you need them outside of your for loop you may do like this:

```
face_section_list = [] # Define a new empty list!
#start sorting from the last face since the last face is the largest in terms of area(w*h)
for face in faces[-1:] :
    x,y,w,h = face
    cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,255),2)

    #extract the required face or the region of the interest
    #Refers to adding an extra 10 pixels on all the sides of the required extracted face
    offset = 10
    #By default face slicing is done in (y,x) manner
    face_section = frame[y-offset:y+h+offset,x-offset:x+w+offset]
    face_section = cv2.resize(face_section,(100,100))
    face_section_list.append(face_section) # Append EVERY face!

    if skip%10==0 : #Store every 10th frame
        face_data.append(face_section)
        print(len(face_data)) #number of faces captured so far
```

And then outside, print every face in order (or do whatever you need to do):

```
for im in face_section_list:
     cv2.imshow("Face section frame",im)
     cv2.waitKey(0) # Zero means "wait until a key is pressed"
```

I've wrote a lot of code for face detection and recognition that you may find helpful, [have a look](https://github.com/decadenza/PAF-Plate-And-Face-Recognition/tree/master/PAF).